# Square Java SDK runniing in Tomcat unable to find jersey-common classes

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, square-connect, square

I am developing angular spring boot web application that uses Square java SDK.

When I tried to access the Square rest api through Square Java SDK, I am getting following exception.

I am running my application in **Tomcat 9 version**.

I checked the .war file and it has **jersey-common** jar and the Injections class and the *createInjectionManager* method.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.createInjectionManager([Lorg/glassfish/jersey/internal/inject/Binder;)Lorg/glassfish/jersey/internal/inject/InjectionManager;
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig$State.initRuntime(ClientConfig.java:386) ~[jersey-client-2.26-b03.jar:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.collection.Values$LazyValueImpl.get(Values.java:341) ~[jersey-common-2.26.jar:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig.getRuntime(ClientConfig.java:723) ~[jersey-client-2.26-b03.jar:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRequest.getConfiguration(ClientRequest.java:286) ~[jersey-client-2.26-b03.jar:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.validateHttpMethodAndEntity(JerseyInvocation.java:141) ~[jersey-client-2.26-b03.jar:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.<init>(JerseyInvocation.java:111) ~[jersey-client-2.26-b03.jar:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.<init>(JerseyInvocation.java:107) ~[jersey-client-2.26-b03.jar:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.<init>(JerseyInvocation.java:98) ~[jersey-client-2.26-b03.jar:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:443) ~[jersey-client-2.26-b03.jar:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.post(JerseyInvocation.java:349) ~[jersey-client-2.26-b03.jar:na]
        at com.squareup.connect.ApiClient.invokeAPI(ApiClient.java:676) ~[connect-2.20191023.0.jar:na]
        at com.squareup.connect.api.CatalogApi.batchRetrieveCatalogObjects(CatalogApi.java:178) ~[connect-2.20191023.0.jar:na]
```

```
import com.squareup.connect.ApiException;
import com.squareup.connect.Configuration;
import com.squareup.connect.api.CatalogApi;
import com.squareup.connect.auth.OAuth;
import com.squareup.connect.models.BatchRetrieveCatalogObjectsRequest;
import com.squareup.connect.models.BatchRetrieveCatalogObjectsResponse;

public class CatalogServiceImpl implements CatalogService {

    @Override
    public BatchRetrieveCatalogObjectsResponse getCatalogItems() {

        ApiClient defaultClient = Configuration.getDefaultApiClient();
        BatchRetrieveCatalogObjectsResponse result = null;

// Configure OAuth2 access token for authorization: oauth2
        OAuth oauth2 = (OAuth) defaultClient.getAuthentication("oauth2");
        oauth2.setAccessToken("");

        CatalogApi apiInstance = new CatalogApi();
        BatchRetrieveCatalogObjectsRequest body = new BatchRetrieveCatalogObjectsRequest();
        // BatchRetrieveCatalogObjectsRequest | An object containing the fields to POST for the request.  See the corresponding object definition for field details.

        try {
            result = apiInstance.batchRetrieveCatalogObjects(body);

            System.out.println(result);
        } catch (ApiException e) {
            System.err.println("Exception when calling CatalogApi#batchRetrieveCatalogObjects");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result;
    }

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.M3</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-aws</artifactId>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-aws-jdbc</artifactId>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-aws-messaging</artifactId>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
                <artifactId>aws-sdk-java</artifactId>
                <version>2.10.0</version>
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup</groupId>
            <artifactId>connect</artifactId>
            <version>2.20191023.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
            <version>2.26</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
            <version>2.26</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.containers/jersey-container-servlet-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.29.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged/jersey-guava -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-guava</artifactId>
            <version>2.26-b03</version>
        </dependency>
<!--        &lt;!&ndash; https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-common &ndash;&gt;-->
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>2.29</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->

<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>2.26</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>2.26-b03</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>
```

Comment: Can you share examples of how you're injecting this? Or how you're using the Square Java SDK. An example would be really helpful to identify why you would be getting a `NoSuchMethodError`. Particularly because there _is_ that method on the [CatalogAPI object](https://github.com/square/connect-java-sdk/blob/master/src/main/java/com/squareup/connect/api/CatalogApi.java#L146)

Comment: added code and pom file to the original question, thanks. The code is slight modification from the example I got from Square developer online documentation.  https://github.com/square/connect-java-sdk/blob/master/docs/CatalogApi.md#batchRetrieveCatalogObjects

Answer (score 1):

Finally got it resolved. It is because of jersey jar versions' incompatability.
These are the correct versions for my setup.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.26</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
        <version>2.26</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.containers/jersey-container-servlet-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.26</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged/jersey-guava -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-guava</artifactId>
        <version>2.26-b01</version>
    </dependency>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
            <version>2.26</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Answer (score 0):

the error can occurred because the same jar file existed on the classpath at the same time.

so open your folder and find same jar and erase it

i'm not good at english..  sry :(

Comment: Checked but only one jar has the class. Thank you for the suggestion